# Xcode - Linker command failed with exit code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-construction, linker

Got a strange issue from Xcode, there aren't code issues and I haven't any idea how to handle with this problem. I also used Google and saw similar questions but the answers weren't useful for me.

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Level._name in:
..../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MobileMaps-bfaaljugbcgusoazfkvdbpbdyiqf/Build /Intermediates/MobileMaps.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MobileMaps.build/Objects-normal/i386/Level-C98F33E28EFA5297.o
/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MobileMaps-bfaaljugbcgusoazfkvdbpbdyiqf/Build/Intermediates/MobileMaps.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MobileMaps.build/Objects-normal/i386/Level-C635B4AD47A32079.o
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Level._type in:
...../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MobileMaps-bfaaljugbcgusoazfkvdbpbdyiqf/Build/Intermediates/MobileMaps.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MobileMaps.build/Objects-normal/i386/Level-C98F33E28EFA5297.o
...../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MobileMaps-bfaaljugbcgusoazfkvdbpbdyiqf/Build/Intermediates/MobileMaps.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MobileMaps.build/Objects-normal/i386/Level-C635B4AD47A32079.o
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Level._binaryImage in:
...../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MobileMaps-bfaaljugbcgusoazfkvdbpbdyiqf/Build/Intermediates/MobileMaps.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MobileMaps.build/Objects-normal/i386/Level-C98F33E28EFA5297.o
..../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MobileMaps-bfaaljugbcgusoazfkvdbpbdyiqf/Build/Intermediates/MobileMaps.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MobileMaps.build/Objects-normal/i386/Level-C635B4AD47A32079.o
 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Level in:
..../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MobileMaps-bfaaljugbcgusoazfkvdbpbdyiqf/Build/Intermediates/MobileMaps.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MobileMaps.build/Objects-normal/i386/Level-C98F33E28EFA5297.o
... ../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MobileMaps-bfaaljugbcgusoazfkvdbpbdyiqf/Build/Intermediates/MobileMaps.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MobileMaps.build/Objects-normal/i386/Level-C635B4AD47A32079.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Level in:
...Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MobileMaps-bfaaljugbcgusoazfkvdbpbdyiqf/Build/Intermediates/MobileMaps.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MobileMaps.build/Objects-normal/i386/Level-C98F33E28EFA5297.o
......Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MobileMaps-bfaaljugbcgusoazfkvdbpbdyiqf/Build/Intermediates/MobileMaps.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MobileMaps.build/Objects-normal/i386/Level-C635B4AD47A32079.o

ld: 5 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Check your "Targets/Compiled Sources", there are probably multiple entries.

Comment: Yes, you are simply either linking the same file twice, or have two difference source files with the same class (more likely).

Comment: `duplicate symbols` can be caused by a few things, e.g. using `#import` on both your .m and .h Some more info here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773974/xcode-duplicate-symbol-error

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read there are many different reasons for this problem and therefore many different solutions but maybe someone will have done the same stupid thing as me and this will help them. I am fairly certain this is not the problem the OP experienced though as my duplicate symbols were in differently named .o files.

Basically be very careful with autocorrect when typing your #import statements. I accidentally imported the .m file instead of the proper .h file and ended up with output similar to what the OP has posted.

Hope this helps somebody!